# Insert nonmatching records from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert

I'm currently finding myself in confusion as this query works fine from within MySQL,  however not too well from PHP.
The return messages  states "operand should contain 1 column(s)". Thank you in advanced

Table1

| TRADE_DATE | OPEN      | HIGH      | LOW       | CLOSE     | VOLUME  |

+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+

| 2015-07-16 | 60.779999 | 60.869999 | 60.75     | 60.830002 | 1050400 |

| 2015-07-15 | 60.34     | 60.560001 | 60.220001 | 60.389999 | 1096400 |

| 2015-07-14 | 60.18     | 60.610001 | 60.169998 | 60.549999 | 1328900 |

| 2015-07-13 | 60.00     | 60.23     | 60.00     | 60.18     | 973300  |

| 2015-07-10 | 59.57     | 59.82     | 59.380001 | 59.720001 | 1506700 |

Table2
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+

| TRADE_DATE | OPEN      | HIGH      | LOW       | CLOSE     | VOLUME  |

+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+

| 2015-07-17 | 60.950001 | 60.950001 | 60.66     | 60.790001 | 731000  |

| 2015-07-16 | 60.779999 | 60.869999 | 60.75     | 60.830002 | 1050400 |

| 2015-07-15 | 60.34     | 60.560001 | 60.220001 | 60.389999 | 1096400 |

| 2015-07-14 | 60.18     | 60.610001 | 60.169998 | 60.549999 | 1328900 |

| 2015-07-13 | 60.00     | 60.23     | 60.00     | 60.18     | 973300

Here's the query

```
    $insertline  = " INSERT INTO `$table1` (SYMBOL, Trade_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj_Close) SELECT SYMBOL, Trade_Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Adj_Close FROM `$table2` WHERE TRADE_DATE NOT IN (SELECT * FROM `$table2`) "; 

    $result6     = mysqli_query($dbcon, $insertline) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) you cannot do a `not in (select [multiple columns])`
(B) You `not in` needs to look at `table1`, not table2, since you are trying to merge data from table2 that covers dates not yet in table1.

Comment: That was a mistake when I wrote it on here thanks for pointing  it out the correction is "NOT IN"... I posted the table data as well

Comment: The goal is to add the 2015-07-17 entry to table one.  Via PHP

Comment: @user5132141 I have edited my answer. Hopefully it provides what you need. Feel free to accept it if so :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, just made the corrections